# Get iframe document from within iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I've been wondering if this is possible, but I only see the opposite answers to what I'm looking for.

I have an iframe with a script that I want to limit to the iframe it is inserted in, without having to look where it is inserted. Now, it first has to search in the whole page's document for the iframe, like this:

```
document.getElementById("iframeId").<do something>.....
```

But I rather have to not look for the iframe at all, because the script is already in the iframe that it has to be in, so why would it still be scoped to the whole document?

The way it's done now doesn't add any value to load the script into the iframe. But I don't like this due to interference with other functionality. Hence, I'm looking to limit the scope of the javascript file inserted in the iframe to the iframe **without searching for the iframe first.**
So actually some object or variable or way where the document object is already the iframe's document.

Thanks!

Comment: See if the script is in a window that has a parent?

Comment: I found out that, if you load a script into an iframe dynamically (using javascript for example,) the script is bound to the place from where you load it. Hence, loading it from a javascript function that is called from the main page, the script is bound to the main page. Fortunately, I've found the best workaround for me so far: I've made a separate .htm file with the script already hardcoded in there. If I then load the .htm file into the iframe, the script inside cannot see anyting more than whats inside the iframe. So the "document"  object for example is then the document of the iframe

Comment: that would be the best solution yes.